# How to create an Angular Material svg iconset

Tags: svg, angular-material

Does anybody know if SVG iconsets are working as of the current version? (1.0.7)

I'm strugling to use some custom svg with the md-icon directive but I haven't managed to see anything on the screen. Is there something broken or it's simply not implemented?

Any example of how to create and use an svg iconset file?

I know I can use the md-svg-src attribute to load one specific svg file providing its url, but that forces me to have all svgs on separated files and it also doesn't play well with the template cache.

**Note:** I'm using SVGs for the icons, not an icon font.